# How to pass a common struct having one of it's fields take on multiple types

Tags: c#, design-patterns, struct

I need to fill a `List` with `SearchReplace` structures. 
I need the `ReplaceValue` field in the structure to also accept other types like an integer or maybe an enumeration that I can use for downstream logic.

I definitely want to avoid boxing by making `ReplaceValue` type object.

```
public struct SearchReplace
{
    public SearchReplace(string data, string searchValue, string replaceValue)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.SearchValue = searchValue;
        this.ReplaceValue = replaceValue;
    }

    string Data;
    string SearchValue;
    string ReplaceValue;
}

public List<SearchReplace> edits;
```

Comment: It largely depends. In a single list, will the `replaceValue` always be the same type? For example, all ints, or all enums, or can the `replaceValue` be mixed in a single list?

Comment: Have you thought about a generic solution with `public SearchReplace(string data, string searchValue, T replaceValue)`?

Comment: @Evan Trimboli.  A single list can have multiple types.

Comment: @Quality Catalyst.  I haven't.  Can you help me understand how to implement that?

Comment: If you need different types and you don't know which you can (potentially) use generics. MSDN user guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx and Pluralsight: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/csharp-generics

Comment: In that case you don't have much choice but for it to be an object, unless you want to create some more complicated logic.

Comment: @Quality Catalyst.  Thank for the links.  I am going through those now.

Comment: If I could see a code example of how to do this I would greatly appreciate it.  Also how the caller detects the actual type from the List.

Comment: _"I definitely want to avoid boxing by making ReplaceValue type object"_ -- why? With a `struct` (i.e. no way to inherit the type), the field _must_ have some definite type, if you're going to mix value instances having different field types in the same list. Boxing is unlikely to cause any real performance problem. Stop worrying about it until you have tried it and can prove there is a problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Downstream I'll need to unbox to handle each type.  Are you saying not to worry about that too?

Comment: I'm open to the struct being a class if I can see a code example of how to do it that way as well.  Especially if performance is likely better over a struct having ReplaceValue of type object.

Comment: _"Are you saying not to worry about that too?"_ -- yes. Boxing/unboxing typically involves short-lived objects, which the .NET GC is optimized to handle reasonably well. Besides, the cost of dealing with them is still likely to be very small compared to whatever else your code is doing. Worrying about boxing in a design like this is very much a premature optimization. IMHO, if you want to worry about _something_, worry about the lack of type-safety involved in having an untyped field in your data structure (something generics would address).

Comment: _"Especially if performance is likely better over a struct having ReplaceValue of type object"_ -- I doubt you'd notice a performance difference one way or the other. First and foremost because the data structure is unlikely to affect performance nearly as much as other elements of your design. Secondly though, because using a reference type replaces the heap object representing the boxed value type with a heap object representing the entire `SearchReplace` type. It's "six of one, half-dozen of the other".

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks Peter.  Really appreciate your insight being so new to C#.  I would honestly really like to use generics for this.  I tried, but ran into the issue of keeping the type i'm passing into the List<> agnostic. eg List<SearchReplace>.

Comment: The only way to use generics would be to declare a base class without the field, and then have specialized generic subclasses with the field. E.g. `class SearchReplaceBase { ... }` and `class SearchReplace<T> : SearchReplaceBase { T ReplaceValue; }`. You'd have a `List<SearchReplaceBase>` and then would need to cast to the appropriate `SearchReplace<T>` to retrieve the `ReplaceValue` if necessary from outside the type.

Comment: Ideally, the type itself would be the only place you'd use the field, in which case the code would already have strongly-typed access to the field. But there's not enough context in your question to say precisely how that would work in your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your struct implemented as a generic;

```
public struct SearchReplace<T>
{
    public SearchReplace(string data, string searchValue, T replaceValue)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.SearchValue = searchValue;
        this.ReplaceValue = replaceValue;
    }

    string Data;
    string SearchValue;
    T ReplaceValue;
}
```

T is just a placeholder for the actual type you want your struct to have. You can implement it like this;

```
        var intSearchReplace = new SearchReplace<int>("data", "searchValue", 15);
        var stringSearchReplace = new SearchReplace<string>("data", "searchValue", "stringReplaceValue");
```

Unfortunately you would not be able to do somethign like this;

```
public List<SearchReplace> edits;
```

You would have to have this;

```
public List<SearchReplace<int>> edits;
```

You would not be able to add the string version to List>, you would have to have different lists for each version of your generic type you created.